# How do I search an int array vs a string array by comparing it to user input

Tags: c#

How do I check if user input matches a number in an array?

I've learned to compare user input or search using a string array, however doing the same with an int array is not working for me.

```
zipCode[i] = 0;
int userZip = 0;

do 
{
    Console.WriteLine( "enter a 5 digit zip code to see if it is supported in our area." );
    Console.WriteLine( );
    Console.WriteLine( "Enter a 0 to exit the program" );
    userZip = 0;
    if ( userZip == zipCode[i] ) 
    {
        found = true;
        if ( found ) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "We support zip code {0}", userZip ); ;
        } 
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "We do not support", userZip );
        }
    }
} while ( userZip != 0 );

Console.ReadLine( );
```

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete. I assume there should be a loop here somewhere on loop variable `i`?

Comment: Do you read any input from your user?  You are going to want to do something like `var userInput=Console.ReadLine();` and then perhaps, parse it to an integer (to check for validity) using `int.TryParse`.  However, you want to check the equality using a string and not an integer.  East coast zip codes start with "0", and when you parse them to integers, you get less than 5 digits.  You might also want to care about "Zip+4" zip codes (like "76543-1234")

Comment: Inside the `if` statement you set `found` to `true` and then immediately test `if (found)`. Why? Of course it will be `true`, since you just set it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the array contents. It's not clear if you have an array of valid zip codes, or an array of numbers (0 through 9), or something else. Also, where is `i` defined?

Comment: The array was just a list of specific zip codes:  int[] zipCode = new int[5] { 96326, 98238, 98438, 98001, 98338 };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I check if user input matches a number in an array?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    static List<string> _zipCodes;

    static Program()
    {
        _zipCodes = new List<string>() { "80205", "80225", "80210" };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string userZip = string.Empty;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a 5 digit zip code to see if it is supported in our area.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a -1 to exit the program");
            userZip = Console.ReadLine();

            if (_zipCodes.Contains(userZip))//<---------------THAT WAY
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("We support zip code {0}", userZip); ;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We do not support zip code {0}", userZip);
            }

        } while (userZip != "-1");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, So I should try listing the array as string instead of integers? I saw an array somewhere using similar code for a list of product codes but the array contained all integers without using strings. Thanks though, i'll study what you did and try t0oemulate it for future projects. Thanks again.

Comment: @Flydog57 has some points regarding zipCodes eg, why they should be stored as strings. I don't know your business requirements -- whether you are handling a small set of local, known zipCodes, international, etc but zipCodes probably shouldn't be handled as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

An `int` array is `Enumerable<int>`, so you could just use `Contains()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: But, again, if you are comparing US zip codes, do it as a string, not an int.  The leading zero in a zip code is considered important

Comment: @Flydog57 True, but I suspect this homework exercise is less about zipcodes and more about learning what `int.Parse` and `Enumerable.Contains` are for.

Comment: I'm just saying: ZipCodes are interesting beasts.  They smell like an integer, but taste like a string.  You can get 5 digit ones, 9 digit ones with a hyphen (10 chars) or 9 digit ones with no hyphens.  You need to handle the case of the town I used to live in (02905) as well as Beverly Hills (92910, or whatever that TV show was).  I'm just saying.

Comment: Ok thank you I will leave it as a string, I thought zip codes would be a good example or a way to use an integer array.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if user input matches a number in an array?

I will answer this question, though I can't post an example using your sample code since it's incomplete and it's not exactly clear what it's supposed to do.

First, let's create a method that gets an integer from the user. This method will continually loop until the user enters a valid integer:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt = null)
{
    int input;
    int row = Console.CursorTop;
    int promptLength = prompt?.Length ?? 0;

    do
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, row);
        Console.Write(prompt + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - promptLength - 1));
        Console.CursorLeft = promptLength;
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input));

    return input;
}
```

Now, we can use that method to get the zip code from the user:

```
int userZipCode = GetIntFromUser("Enter a 5 digit zip code to see if it's supported: ");
```

Now I'm assuming you have an array of zip codes that are supported. Perhaps something like:

```
private static int[] GetSeattleZipCodes()
{
    return new []
    {
        98101, 98102, 98103, 98104, 98105, 98106, 98107, 98108, 98109, 98110,
        98111, 98112, 98113, 98114, 98115, 98116, 98117, 98118, 98119, 98121,
        98122, 98124, 98125, 98126, 98127, 98129, 98131, 98133, 98134, 98136,
        98138, 98139, 98141, 98144, 98145, 98146, 98148, 98154, 98155, 98158,
        98160, 98161, 98164, 98165, 98166, 98168, 98170, 98174, 98175, 98177,
        98178, 98181, 98185, 98188, 98190, 98191, 98194, 98195, 98198, 98199
    };
}
```

So, now we have an `int` user input, and an `int[]` of valid zip codes, so to see if the array of valid zip codes contains the user zip code, we can just use the `Contains` method:

```
int[] seattleZipCodes = GetSeattleZipCodes();
bool found = seattleZipCodes.Contains(userZipCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

TheFastCat beat me, but:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<string> zipCodes = new string[] { "90210", "94102", "98101", "80014" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("enter a 5 digit zip code to see if it is supported in our area, or '0' to exit");
            do {
                // Read next line
                string userZip = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                // Exit program?
                if (userZip == "0")
                    break;

                // Validate input
                if (userZip.Length != 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Zip code {0} is {1} characters; expected 5", userZip, userZip.Length);
                    continue;
                }
                int n;
                bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(userZip, out n);
                if (!isNumeric)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Zip code {0} must be numeric", userZip);
                    continue;
                }

                // Finally, see if our zip code matches a zip code in the list
                bool found = zipCodes.Contains(userZip);
                if (found)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("We support zip code {0}", userZip); ;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("We do not support " + userZip);
                }
            } while (true);
            Console.WriteLine("Done: exiting program");
        } 
    }
}
```

Note:

1. Initializing the list
2. Validating the input
3. Using [IEnumerable.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) ... *without* necessarily messing with LINQ.
4. Use of "break" and "continue" to control the loop, *without* necessarily needing an extraneous variable.

Answer (score -1):

TheFastCat and Rufus L done great job.
I just want to add an example. Using 'var' datatypes makes things easy and durable as well in C#
This example demonstrates both 'int' and 'string' using var datatypes in both cases. Good luck haberjin.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        //var ZipCodes = new List<string>() { "04846", "40569", "76859","54896", "84623" }; // ZipCodes are stored as a string in a List
        var ZipCodes = new List<int>() { 04846, 40569, 76859, 54896, 84623 }; // ZipCodes are stored as an int in a List

        //var userZip = "";
        var userZip = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a 5 digit zip code to see if it is supported in our area.");

            //userZip = Console.ReadLine(); // Enable to receive userZip as a string
            userZip = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // receive userZip as an int

            if (ZipCodes.Contains(userZip))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We support zip code {0}", userZip);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We do not support", userZip);
            }

            //} while (userZip != "0");
        } while (userZip != 0);
    }
```

Comment: I was using int userZip = 0, As Rufus pointed out I was also setting found to true. I removed it and used var instad of int.